# How to transmit byte array between javascript and NPAPI Plugin

Tags: plugins, npapi

I have an NPRuntime plugin in which I need to transmit raw data  (`byte array`'s) between javascript and my plugin. As I understand byte arrays can not be send using `NPVariant` object. That`s why I search for solutinon, and find this for transmit data:

1. Using Strings in base64 encoding;
2. Printing byte by byte in string ( http://code.google.com/p/npapi-file-io/ ), like `[92, 32, 43...]`;
3. NPStream as temp file.

My question is how can I call NPP_Write for NPStream from javascript.
In "C" I have NPP_Write(that write to my plugin), NPN_Write(write to browser) that I can use for transmit data.
http://www.podgoretsky.com/ftp/docs/internet/Netscape%20Plug-Ins/ch8.htm.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use NPStream to send data to the plugin from Javascript.  The closest I'm aware of is that it's possible to set an attribute on your object or embed tag and have it open a stream on the plugin to download that file automatically (though I've never done this so I can't give you details).

The sad fact is that NPAPI has no reliable way to do what you want.  Options 1 and 2 are the only options you have, and neither is fantastic.  I guess the one other thing you could do is create a web server to run inside the plugin and then talk to that from javascript using jsonp. [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) has a built-in but undocumented webserver in the library HTTPService that was used for things like that at one time.